# How do I stop clicking next too many times from breaking my image rotator?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate, settimeout, setinterval

Im new to jquery and have been trying to code a simple image rotator, it works well at the moment except for the fact that if you click the "next" of "prev" buttons too many times very quickly it will break the image rotator.

Here is the html:

```
<div id="viewport">
    <div id="imageContainer">
        <div class="image" style="background-color:red;">
            <div class="title"><p>This is the title of the post</p></div>
        </div>
        <div class="image" style="background-color:green;">
            <div class="title"><p>This is the title of the post</p></div>
        </div>
        <div class="image" style="background-color:yellow;">
            <div class="title"><p>This is the title of the post</p></div>
        </div>
        <div class="image" style="background-color:brown;">
            <div class="title"><p>This is the title of the post</p></div>
        </div>
        <div class="image" style="background-color:purple;">
            <div class="title"><p>This is the title of the post</p></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<input type="button" name="prev" id="prev" value="prev" />
<input type="button" name="next" id="next" value="next" />
```

and jquery:

```
var ic = $('#imageContainer');
    var numItems = $('.image').size();
    var position = 0;
    ic.css('left', '0px');

    var inter; 
    var rotateTimeout;

    function rotate(){
        inter = setInterval(function(){
             if (position == (numItems - 1)) {
                console.log(position);
                $('.image').first().insertAfter($('.image').last());
                ic.css('left', '+=400px');
                position--;
            }
            ic.animate({opacity: 0.2, left: "-=400px"}, 1500, function(){
                ic.animate({opacity: 1.0}, 1000);
            });

            position += 1;
        }, 6000);

    }
    rotate();

    $('#prev').click(function () {
        console.log(position);
        if (position == 0) {
            $('.image').last().insertBefore($('.image').first());
            ic.css('left', '-=400px');
            position++;
        }
        ic.animate({
            left: "+=400px"
        });
        position -= 1;

        clearInterval(inter);
        clearTimeout(rotateTimeout);
        rotateTimeout = setTimeout(rotate, 10000);


    });

    $('#next').click(function () {
        if (position == (numItems - 1)) {
            console.log(position);
            $('.image').first().insertAfter($('.image').last());
            ic.css('left', '-400px');
            position--;
        }
        ic.animate({
            left: "-=400px"
        });
        position += 1;

        clearInterval(inter);
        clearTimeout(rotateTimeout);
        rotateTimeout = setTimeout(rotate, 10000);



    });
```

Here is a [demo of the rotator](http://chrismepham.com/sites/test/livesearch.html).

So how can I either stop the user from clicking the button too quickly, or perhaps only account for a click per two seconds to allow the rotator to do what it needs?

Answer (score 1):

To limit function call frequency you can use some "Throttle" function. For example `_.throttle` from [Underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/#throttle) or any other implementation. It is not necessary to use whole library, only required function could be copied from there.

The event handler attachment will look like this:

```
$('#prev').click( _.throttle(function () { yours code... }, 2000) );
```